# Importing modules Python from folder to folder

Tags: python, import

I can't find an answer:
I have 1 folder named "Program" at deskop location. Inside "Program" folder, I have 2 folders: "zebra" and "lew". In each "zebra" and "koza", I wrote simple code - print("here i am") saved under different names: `zebra1` and `lew 1`. If I write the code in the main folder and import it, it works fine, but when I wanna import `zebra 1` to `lew2`, it doesn't allow me. I tried to add path but it doesn't work.....

```
.Program
Drukuj.py - from zebra import zebra1, from lew import lew1
.....zebra
       ....zebra1 - print("here i am zebra")
.....lew
       ....lew1 - print("here i am lew")
       ....lew2 - from zebra import zebra1  - it doesnt work
```

Can anyone show my full way to do it?  with full print(sys.path) ?

Comment: please add folders details as screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You have to append the path of folders containing the scripts you Want to import in sys.path:

```
import sys 
sys.path.append(PATH_OF_FOLDER_CONTAINING_LEW2)
```